# How to identify grid shift file used by osgeo in Python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, osgeo

I wrote a Python script reprojecting points from a source coordinate reference system (SCRS) to a target one (TCRS) both identified by an EPSG code.
I would like my python script to retrieve details about the grid shift file it uses when doing reprojections from NAD83 to NAD27.

Such information is given by CS2CS in a terminal window when the variable PROJ_DEBUG is set to ON.

Can my python script retrieve the same information?
Any ideas?

Thanks

My script is:

```
from osgeo import osr

#Input coordinates
xin = 436898.0
yin = 5577554.0

# Transformation setup from NAD83 UTM Z15 to NAD27 UTM Z15
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(26915)
trs = osr.SpatialReference()
trs.ImportFromEPSG(26715)
rsTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(srs,trs)

# Doing transformation
(xout, yout, zout) = rsTrans.TransformPoint(xin,yin)
```